# Python Pandas output rounded DataFrame to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a spreadsheet containing (among other things) rows of people and their education levels, which I've read into a DataFrame.

I am trying to return a dictionary containing relative frequencies which have been rounded to 3 decimal places.

```
return self.data['education'].value_counts(normalize=True).round(3)
```

returns

```
BA/BS       0.458
Some Col    0.250
PostGrad    0.167
High Sch    0.125
Name: education, dtype: float64
```

but

```
return self.data['education'].value_counts(normalize=True).round(3).to_dict()
```

returns

```
{u'High Sch': 0.125, u'BA/BS': 0.45800000000000002, u'PostGrad': 0.16700000000000001, u'Some Col': 0.25}
```

I'm just kind of flummoxed by this. Can anyone shed some light on what's going on?

Comment: could be a bug it looks like the rounding just affects the output and that the fundamental type is still float so you get the minor fractional part persisting, one possible solution would be to do `self.data['education'].value_counts(normalize=True).round(3).astype(str).to_dict()` but this will put the values in quotes though

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.3f}'.format
```

Answer (score 0):

np.round does not do what you think it does.

For example run this:

```
np.round(3.1231,3)
```

which returns

```
3.1230000000000002
```

np.round is transforming into the nearest possible representation of the rounded number (3.123), and the closest one it can do with the precision it has is the number you see above (3.1230000000000002)

What you are also seeing in your example is that, when you are calling the object

```
return self.data['education'].value_counts(normalize=True).round(3)
```

pd.Series is performing some trimming on the output.

```
my_s = pd.Series([3.123,2], index=['a','b'])
my_s
```

prints

```
a    3.123
b    2.000
dtype: float64
```

but my_s[a] prints

```
 3.1230000000000002
```

What you want to do is to format the representation of the number, in the way the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The response by MaxU works for printing but does not change anything when `to_dict` is used.

This is what I have used to solve this issue:

```
my_s = pd.Series([0.12345,0.45678], index=['a','b'])
my_s = my_s.apply(lambda x: '{:,.3%}'.format(x))
```

this gives:

```
my_s.to_dict()
{'b': '45.678%', 'a': '12.345%'}
```